# combine multiple queries with count and group

Tags: mysql

How do i combine the two mysql queries below to a single query?

```
SELECT R12NC,  COUNT(*) AS `count1` FROM alink where Option_a = 1 GROUP BY  R12NC
SELECT R12NC,  COUNT(*) AS `count2` FROM alink where Option_x = 1 GROUP BY  R12NC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways. If you want just two columns, use a UNION

```
SELECT R12NC,  COUNT(*) AS `count1` FROM alink where Option_a = 1 GROUP BY  R12NC
UNION
SELECT R12NC,  COUNT(*) AS `count2` FROM alink where Option_x = 1 GROUP BY  R12NC
```

If you want 3 columns then something like:

```
SELECT R12NC, SUM(CASE WHEN Option_a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `count1`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Option_x = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `count2`
FROM alink
GROUP BY  R12NC
```

Comment: If the two counts were same for some `R12NC` value, UNION would eliminate one of the rows as a duplicate – not necessarily the OP's intention.

Comment: Works Perfect :) Thanks DigitalD. Only problem is I am seeing a NULL row for R12NC which i was not seeing when I ran the queries individually

Answer (score 0):

By using the `case` statement, nested in an aggregation function:

```
SELECT R12NC,
       sum(case when Option_a = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as `count1`,
       sum(case when Option_x = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as `count2`
FROM alink
GROUP BY  R12NC
```

Comment: The syntax seems to be correct.  Are you running any other queries in the batch?

Comment: only running this from phpMyAdmin